# How to generilize the the following summation.

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, power-series

While searching for a summation formula I come accross the following equation on wikipedia [Equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_series)
$$\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n}{k^m z^k}=\left(z\frac{d}{dz}\right)^m\frac{z-z^{n+1}}{1-z}$$

So I tried to simplify it but it is getting complex and I am unable to come up with any sort form this summation equation. Please help me

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To which equation are you referring? You just linked to the Wiki article and there are lots of expressions on there..

Comment: Sorry for inconvienince image updated.

Comment: What do you want to do with this? Do you want to prove it? Do you want to otherwise generalize it? It's not clear what you intend in your post.

Comment: suppose we are given n m and z how can we compute the sum of the series modulo a prime number. I was solving this problem http://www.spoj.com/problems/MOON1/ I have solve the easier version with small n but have problem with large value of n.

Comment: You should have directly asked what you want to prove...

Comment: Can some one help  me?  thanks.